# Best way to indicate a good ground connection?

Tags: led, ground, design, indicator

I'm working with 120VAC, and I'd like to have an LED indicator light showing that there is a connection to ground (earth). Like the way a receptacle tester does.

I could connect the LED between hot and ground using a resistor or capacitor to drop the voltage, but I'd rather not be using the ground to "complete" the circuit.

Is there a way to do this without using the ground wire for the current?

Comment: why would you require a connection to hot? ... maybe something that detects RF interference on the ground wire

Comment: What kind of receptacle tester you mean? The simplest ones simply have a LED and a resistor from live to ground. Or any other arrangement that either turns a LED on if ground is present, or shunts current away from LED to earth to turn a LED off if a ground is present. But those kind of testers don't require a very good ground and the wiring may be bad even if your LEDs say it's there.

Comment: Jsolota: I may be missing something, but I don't know how to light an LED without a power source. I don't think I understand your question.  Justme: I don't actually know how receptacle testers work. I do know that an LED or neon lamp lights up if a ground connection is present.